# como obtengo los valores de un id_ USER? ALEATORIO

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Como hago para obtener un ID DE USUARIO aleatorio que ya se encuentra almacenado en el child "USUARIOS". El en child "USUARIOS" estan almacenado el id de cada usuario legeado con facebook y cada uno de ellos contiene su respectivo datos de usuario. Y lo quiere es que al presionar un botón  seleccione cualquier ID DE USUARIO y que muestre su nombre, país, foto, monedas y email. Por favor ayudennnn[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, lo estas desarrollando en Android o en Kotlin <3

Answer (score 0):

este seria un codigo ejemplo a tu problema

En java

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Para obtener el id
        String id = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        // Esto es para obtener el usuario mas no su uid
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuarios.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
```

En Kotlin

```
val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        // Para obtener el id
        val id = dataSnapshot.getKey()

        // Esto es para obtener el usuario mas no su uid
        val post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuarios::class.java)
        // ...
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
        // ...
    }
}
```

Mas informacion:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

Primero añadimos una clase POJO que contenga todos los datos de nuestro usuario, y añadimos un campo mas llamado userID para almacenar el id de cada usuario

**Importante: los nombres de las variables deben coincidir con los nombres de las variables en Firebase para poder obtener los datos**

```
public static class Usuario {

  public String Email;
  public String ID;
  public String userID;
  ...

  public Usuario(String Email, String ID...) {
    // ...
  }

  public Usuario() {}

}
```

Luego creamos la referencia a donde vamos a obtener los datos

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Usuarios");
```

Para finalizar, traemos todos los datos del usuario e incorporamos en el objeto, el ID del usuario que se esta trayendo, vamos a guardar todos los usuarios en una lista para poder accederlos luego

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();
     for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       Usuario user = snap.getValue(Usuario.class);
       user.setUserID(snap.getKey());
       user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
       ...
       lista.add(user);
  }

 //Accedemos a los elementos de la lista (donde deberian estar todos los usuarios)

  for(int it = 0 : i < lista.size() ; i ++){
   Log.d("Usuario"+i+" Email":+list.get(i).getEmail());
}

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```